# Regex validation on smart contracts

Tags: eosio-code, development, contract-development, dapp-development, code

Is is possible to use regex validation in a smart contract?

Comment: Can you give an example of something you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I wanted to check the correct sintax of a public key like (EOS[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{50})

Comment: Surely that is just string manipulation though right? Or do you want to use a particular library to do it? If so which library?